# Need to enter title before I make blog entry

Tags: organic-groups, nodes

I have installed the [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) to make a multi-blog site. The problem is that when I try to create a blog entry, I only get a "Title"-field, which I need to save, and then edit the entry to enter the body text.

Any ideas how to fix this so I get the full blog entry fields when I click "Add content".

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the OG field permissions `Configuration\Organic Groups\OG field permission overview`.

Edit the node type and check the 'Edit Body field' and 'View Body field'.